Can a home folder be created after a user is created without one?
I just installed Ubuntu 24.04 and I've already hit a problem of things changing with no notice.
On Ubuntu 20.04, when I created a system user using adduser, it created a home folder for that user:
$ sudo adduser --system --group barney
Adding system user `barney' (UID 114) ...
Adding new group `barney' (GID 119) ...
Adding new user `barney' (UID 114) with group `barney' ...
Creating home directory `/home/barney' ...

Now, in Ubuntu 24.04, the exact same command suddenly works a different way:
$ sudo adduser --system --group barney
info: Selecting UID from range 100 to 999 ...

info: Selecting GID from range 100 to 999 ...
info: Adding system user `barney' (UID 112) ...
info: Adding new group `barney' (GID 112) ...
info: Adding new user `barney' (UID 112) with group `barney' ...
info: Not creating `/nonexistent'.

No home folder is created.  Okay, fine, one of the thousand paper cuts of using Linux that I've gotten calloused to.
Can I correct this by manually adding the /home/barney/ directory?  That is, if I run
$ sudo mkdir /home/barney
$ sudo chown barney:barney /home/barney
$ sudo chmod 775 /home/barney

is that precisely the same as /home/barney/ having been created as the home folder for barney at the time the user was added, or are there further complications under the hood that I'm not aware of?

You also have to add the /home/barney to the /etc/passwd field 6.

Why create a system user? Create a normal user. Typically system users didn't need a home.

See this Q&A for more.

See also: man adduser

If you research the "usermod" command, there seems to be an option to create a missing home directory that way:
sudo usermod --home /home/barney barney

I have not tried it myself, but have used usermod to fix incorrect groups and to match user IDs across servers.

usermod does not create the directory you specify, but it does add it to /etc/passwd as one commenter to the question pointed out.  A combination of this command and $ sudo mkdir /home/barney, plus adjusting ownership and permissions, covers everything everyone has mentioned.  Unless anyone can think of anything else that needs to be fixed, it looks like this works.  Thanks!
